# Padding parameter values in contract low-level call

Tags: solidity, abi

In the following example:

```
contract_address.call(bytes4(sha3("function_name(types)")),parameters_values)
```

should we pad the parameters values to 32 bytes? Because I have seen code like

```
if (!addressOfA.call(bytes4(keccak256("f1(bool,uint256)")), true, 3)) {
    throw;
}
```

but according to the [ABI specification](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html), "true" and "3" should be padded, where clearly in the example are not.

Comment: There should be no space between your parameter values in the string that you hash: `keccak256("f1(bool,uint256)")` instead of `keccak256("f1(bool, uint256)")`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But this is a minor detail. The question is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding is not needed, from the [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#members-of-addresses):

> - call, callcode and delegatecall
>
> Furthermore, to interface with contracts that do not adhere to the ABI, the function call is provided which takes an arbitrary number of arguments of any type. ***These arguments are padded to 32 bytes and concatenated***. One exception is the case where the first argument is encoded to exactly four bytes. In this case, it is not padded to allow the use of function signatures here

Comment: Didn't read that part in the documentation. Thanks